# If maximum stamina gets reduced during an environment card, when the card is discarded, do I return to max?

Tags: arkham-horror

If an environment card makes my max stamina go down 1, I would lose a stamina token.  However, if a new environment card shows and I haven't taken any stamina damage, do I get to move it back up to my maximum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you wouldn't.

You don't instantly gain stamina/sanity when your maximum increases, thus you also wouldn't gain stamina/sanity if a penalty to your maximum was removed.

Comment: I believe you but I am curious how you know you don't gain when your stat increases.  Is that in the rules, on the card or just intuition?  I've never encountered that, so just got curious.  Thanks.

Comment: @joedragons Gaining/losing current stamina/sanity through changes to your maximum aren't covered anywhere in the rules (or the FAQs), except that the rules say your current can never be more than your maximum. So I take it as a rule through explicit omission, as that would be the kind of thing that (I think) would be explicitly stated. Also the general consensus on the FFG Arkham forums (at least a few years ago when I was a regular there) is that if something isn't specified in the rules or FAQ, play the way that least benefits the players.